Is there content difference between Exalted Third Edition, Exalted Third Edition Deluxe and Exalted Third Edition Ultra Deluxe?
From what I can tell there appear to be three different books for the Exalted 3e core rulebook:

Exalted Third Edition
Exalted Third Edition Deluxe
Exalted Third Edition Ultra Deluxe

Are there any differences between the three content-wise such as Ultra Deluxe edition including extra charms, or extra setting information?

You are referring to the print edition books, yes?

No, they're the same book in content — only the physical format differs, with the Deluxe and Ultra Deluxe offering increasing amounts of ornamentation. The Deluxe version has higher-quality covers, gilt edges, and a ribbon bookmark; the Ultra Deluxe has that and a "golden metal" sigil sheet inset in the front cover.

The deluxe also has a better cover material.

Cover, Paper & Print Quality
The only difference between the two variants of Print On Demand of the core book Exalted 3rd Edition offered through drivetroughrpg are the type of paper and ink used.
Covers

The Deluxe edition has a different, white cover with just the cartouche embossed in gold. It's supposed to have the same content, but even better print with gold-edged pages and a gold silk ribbon bookmark. The Ultra-Deluxe edition has an even more flashy all-golden embossed metal sheet inset in the cover. Otherwise it is the same as the Deluxe edition.
Pricepoint?
The standard print costs ca 60, the premium print 145, so about 85 bucks for premium paper and color ink. The deluxe edition with the gold trimmed pages costs 350, which reflects the much smaller quantity of these being printed, while the Ultra Deluxe costs a whopping 450.
But, that is not all cash for the publisher: about 30% of that go to the retailer, and no small amount goes to the printer before anything is earned. So how much does a tiny print run cost? Having 250 books printed of roughly the basic Exalted 3 settings I was offered about 46 USD per book, but as you order more, things get increasingly cheaper. Having the closest to the Deluxe edition made with the same print run would cost 53.30 USD per book. The Ultra-Deluxe with the metal sheet wasn't priceable, but having a letter-sized page engraved and gilded can cost about 50-100 USD on its own.
